# Mollifier of a subharmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

Suppose $D$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $m\geq2$, and $u(x)$ is locally integrable on $D$. We know that if $\omega$ is an open set that is included with its closure to $D$, the mollifier $u_{n}$ of $u$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)
exists on $\omega$ for $n$ sufficiently big. We know also that if $u$ is subharmonic on $D$, then the mollifier is subharmonic on $\omega$ for $n$ sufficiently big.

My question is: suppose $u$ is locally integrable on $D$ but  subharmonic on $D\setminus F$, where $F$ is a closed set with empty interior. Can we say that $u_{n}$ is subharmonic on  $\omega\setminus F$ for $n$ big enough?

Comment: I think yes... Shouldn't the same proof work? what's the issue

Comment: The sequence is defined by 
$$u_{n}(x)=\int u(x-t)\phi_{n}(t)dt.$$
In the regular case, where $u$ is subharmonic on $D$, $x-t$ belongs also to $\omega$ and so $x\mapsto u(x-t)$ is subharmonic on $\omega$. But now, what if $x\in \omega$ but $x-t\in F$? How can we have subharmonicity of $x\mapsto u(x-t)$, or circumvent it?

Comment: For any fixed $x$, since $F$ is closed, if we take $\phi$ to have compact support (which we may do), then for $n$ large enough and $t$ in the support of $\phi_n$, $x-t \not \in F$.

Comment: Consider $x\in F$ and a sequence $x_{m}$ outside $F$ that converges to $x$. For a fixed $n$ I cannot say that $u_{n}$ is subharmonic at a neighborhood of each $x_{m}$, can I?

Comment: Does the closure of $\omega$ avoid $F$? If so, then my previous comment applies uniformly to $x \in \omega$, and the answer to your last comment is "yes, if each $x_m$ is in $\omega$". If the closure of $\omega$ intersects $F$, then I'm not sure...

Comment: Indeed, the closure of $\omega$ may intersect $F$. But even if $F$ is a subset of $\omega$, I don't see how $x-t$ does not belong to $F$, if $x\in F$ and $n$ is fixed?

Comment: nobody is talking about $F$ being a subset of $\omega$. I was saying $\overline{\omega} \cap F = \emptyset$. If $\overline{\omega}\cap F = \emptyset$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\omega$ that doesn't intersect $F$; if we take $n$ large enough, then for any $x \in \omega$, if $t$ is in the support of $\phi_n$, it will be the case that $x-t \in U$.

Comment: In this case, of course.

Comment: I don't see why $u_n$ should be defined on $\omega$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Consider, for example, $D = \{|z| < 1\}, F = \{0\}, \omega = \{|z| < .5\}, u(x) = \log|x|$.

Comment: You are right but here $u(z)$ is subharmonic everywhere including on $F$.

Comment: So? You asked about $u_n$ being subharmonic.